# What can I use besides Sessions in order to use the following method as an API method?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-session

I have a quiz app with a laravel back-end and Vue front-end. I am working on developing an API for this app. However, the problem I have encountered is that I need an API endpoint that: returns a question from Questions table - but it needs to:

1. Return a question at random every time the method is called
2. Not be a question that user has already seen (unless all questions have been seen)

Up until now, I have been randomising the questions collection using the shuffle method, and relying on Sessions to store the ids of the unseenQuestions.

However, as API calls are stateless, sessions will not work. I was wonder what ways I could get around this?

```
public function random(Module $module, $category){
    // Get question ids in randomised order (for a given module + category)
    $questions =  Question::CategoryForModule(1, $module->id)->shuffle()->pluck('id');

    // Name and Get unseenQuestions
    $sessionName = 'unseenQuestions_' . $category .  strval($module->id); //unseenQuestions_anatomy_2

    if (session()->has($sessionName)) {
        $unseenQuestions = session()->get($sessionName);

    } else {
        $unseenQuestions = collect($questions);

    }
    // Pop new Question
    $newQuestionID = $unseenQuestions->shift();;

    // Store unseenQuestions OR remove unseenQuestions (if it has no items);
    if ($unseenQuestions->count() == 0) {
        session()->forget($sessionName);
    } else {
        session()->put($sessionName, $unseenQuestions);
    }

    return new QuestionResource(Question::find($newQuestionID));
}
```

Comment: API calls are not exactly stateless, they just don't start the session. You can still use cookies (but probably shouldn't) or pass a user specific API key that in turn is used to determine who the user is (usually people use OAuth2 for this).

Comment: API calls should be designed to be stateless and cookies MUST not be used. Cookies are a way browsers use to store session data, but an API endpoint might be called from a mobile app, a command line interface etc etc

Comment: What I essentially need is something to store the unseenQuestions between calls to the random() method (without having to persist to database). I was previously using sessions to do this. Would tokens be the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take one of these approaches to do this

- Authenticate your API calls: every user has a token that will authenticate the call. Then whenever you extract a question from a DB you store (in DB) the question as `seen` by the user
- Send along with your API an array of `seen` questions. This approach IMHO is to be avoided because it is exploitable, and you delegate the client to decide wether a question has been seen or not.

I would go for the first option.

Comment: I would ideally like to avoid persisting to a DB because the seen questions need to be stored temporarily. Once all the questions in the quiz are seen, the seen questions need to be reset to 0.

Comment: When the user has seen all the question you can delete some rows from a database. What is the difference with session? if it's time based you can think about using Cache. But, again, you should not rely on the client, so you have to store this information in the server. The medium (DB, file, key/value store) is irrelevant.